# Celery should execute task on call even if queue/concurrency is occupied

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

- I have a celery app in Django where I defined all periodically wise tasks with specific intervals.
- I have initiated celery worker with `5 concurrency`

`celery -A appname worker --loglevel=info -B -c  5`

- now each and every task defined will execute periodically w.r.t their interval & get queued up if they are more than 5 active tasks present.
- Now I want to define a task such that it should execute whenever it called. No matter of queue or anything.

```
send_task('task_name',[],get_task_kwargs)
```

- Whenever I called `send_task` it should execute immediately without getting queued up at concurrency of celery worker.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee that your task will run when a task is invoked.  The best you can do is assign this particular task to its own queue.  That way it will always start executing so long as there is not another task of the same type in front of it.

Comment: is there any way to define separate workers for it?

Comment: Yes.  If you use separate queues and routing, you can start up different workers on different queues using the `-Q` flag when starting a worker.

Comment: Can you please provide a detailed overview of the solution to overcome such a problem?

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html , I guess we can use `celery calling tasks` to execute the task immediately but how we can invoke it to run in separate worker so that it's not queued up with current workers.